# Why is the letter C so spoiled in many languages?

Tags: etymology

So in some Romane languages, C makes a /k/ or /s/ sound and a k or ch sound in Italian? How did that all happen?

Answer (score 1):

Spoiled is the wrong word. It's a common phonological change as might be expected to occur in any language in history. In fact the exact same change occured in old english, and similarly in the development satem languages like sanskrit
But in terms of the actual process there was an intermediate phase in vulgar latin/proto-romance where the /k/ became palatalised before a front vowel (as well as did the /g/). In Italian dialects the /k/ became articulated as /tʃʲ/ while in western romance it was /tsʲ/ which with time became simply /s/. elsewhere /g/ > /dʒ/, /tj/ > /ts/, /nj/ > /ɲɲ/, /lj/ > /ʎʎ/

Comment: So that's not a problem?